# Is there any different model for universe which can create life?

Tags: resource-recommendations, universe, biology, laws-of-physics

We know, our universe has four forces (there can be more than four) and some laws. And laws, forces, and particles consequently give the universe the ability to produce living things. Can we create such a (hypothetic) separate universe that is capable of creating living things? Is there any research paper on different models for different universe?

Comment: The first question would be What does "living things" mean to you?  It's actually an astonishingly difficult question, to which there is very limited consensus.  It's even more difficult to define when you aren't bounding yourself by the limitations of our known universe.

Comment: @CortAmmon right, Correct, first we need to define primary life. Do you have any ideas(\suggestions)

Comment: @Pruthviraj, _self replication_ mitght be part of a working definition of "life," but you'll need more than just that if you don't want to have to say that _[tin pest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_pest)_ is "alive."

Comment: Maybe "Conway's Game of Life" helps here.

Comment: @Pruthviraj - Conway's Game of Life is a good example of the problem. Yes, one can make self-replicators but they are very artificial, very fragile patterns that would not persist in a "natural" GoL environment. Indeed, one can make arbitrary Turing-machines and even GoL simulations inside the world. It is "lifelike", yet seem to lack many properties that make life possible in our world (we do not explode into chaos when hit by a single particle). What cellular automaton rules give rise to Type IV complex "physics" is still not well understood.

Comment: @AndersSandberg, _You_ are an extremely small, extremely rare, and extremely fragile pattern in a universe that contains things like supernovae and supermassive black holes and millions of light years of absolute, freezing emptiness between galaxies.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - Yes, but I do not disintegrate into contagious chaos if hit by a single photon. Game of Life worlds are far more unstable than our world, because of the lack of conservation laws.

Comment: You see in a hypothetical parallel universes we need to have all four fundamental forces gravity, electromagnetism, strong and weak nuclear force of similar strengths with respect our universe.Any deviation from there (more than a factor of 10) will create conditions impossible for life to exist. This all gets complex when we involve dark energy and dark matter and I still am unsure about those two

Answer (score 5):

There is a fairly extensive literature on "[fine tuning](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fine-tuning/)": [what settings of the fundamental constants of physics allow universes that can sustain life as we know it](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0511774v3). Most such papers demonstrate that if one change parameters beyond a certain range some important property such as having stellar fusion, stable matter, molecular bonds etc. will fail, and one cannot have our kind of life.

The problem with this is that one can find alternative solutions for problems if one is ingenious enough. For example, in a more higher-dimensional universe it looks like electron orbitals would tend to merge with atomic nuclei in ways that look like you cannot have chemistry (see e.g. *The Anthropic Cosmological Principle* by Barrow and Tipler). Greg Egan, in his novel *[Diaspora](http://www.gregegan.net/DIASPORA/15/15.html)*, however discusses (based on quantum mechanics) how this might not be true for heavier elements. Also, radically different universes may allow radically different possibilities we have few intuitions about (Egan's later novels are good examples of how one can make science-based fictional settings with [different physics](http://www.gregegan.net/DICHRONAUTS/DICHRONAUTS.html)).

So the problem here is that while one can come up with alternative physics models, we do not have great tools for inferring all the nontrivial implications. Understanding the standard model field equations does not obviously tell you that there are things like protons and neutrons, let alone that they form nuclei because of residual strong forces, and that these nuclei attract electrons whose orbitals lead to chemical bonds... that, for certain very particular nuclei, pressures and temperatures can form self-replicating life. Life in this case is on top of several very nontrivial levels of emergence.

One can make negative arguments of the kind "in universes with this kind of physics there are no stable systems" or "in universes with this kind of physics there are no long-range interactions" that perhaps rule out life. One can also make toy physics that explicitly allow interactions one needs for one's definition of life (whatever that is). But we do not have a general theory yet.

Answer (score 1):

To add a few cents to Anders' answer. In principle, for the existence of life, it should be enough to have a universe whose laws are complex enough to allow universal (or Turing complete) computations. A given Turing complete system of laws can simulate any other Turing complete system of laws,  given the right initial conditions.

It is not difficult to generate Turing complete laws. Cellular automaton rule 110 is universal, same as Conway game of life. What this means is that any of these two simple systems are in principle capable of recreating a level of complexity similar to that of our current universe. The fact that Conway's game of life only results in very simple "organisms" is mainly due to the short spatial and time size of the simulations.

A (perhaps outdated) but amazing book about what life means and different computational approaches to evolve it is  The Origins of Order, by Stuart Kauffman.